# How to make jenkins build pass if cucumber scenarios pass percentage is 80%

Tags: jenkins, cucumber-jvm

How to make jenkins build pass if cucumber JVM scenarios pass percentage is 80%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cucumber reports plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cucumber-reports/) can be used for this.
The plugin has a lot of options where the build is marked as failure or unstable.

For example:

> failedScenariosPercentage (optional)
>
> Maximum percentage of failed scenarios above which build result is
>   changed.

Comment: Thanks, out of 20 scenarios, 10 failed. So under Build Status - Cucumber Reports in Jenkins I gave Number of failed scenarios = 10 Still job is not passed. Please let me know what is wrong? PS: Other field Build Status is Left Unchanged, not sure if I had to change this as well along with first one?. Also I did not see failedScenariosPercentage field

Comment: The field exists for sure as long as you are using a declarative pipeline.

Comment: Its declarative pipeline as I see in this link https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin it does not display percentage parameter. Also "Build Status" is by default "Left Unchanged" it has 2 more values Fail and Unstable but does not have PASS. Even if I use "Number of failed scenarios" parameter how can I make build pass?