# How to force entire jenkins job to pass based on no. of cucumber scenarios passed despite some failures

Tags: jenkins, cucumber-jvm

Is there any way to make jenkins build pass if cucumber JVM scenarios pass percentage is 50%

For this in the cucumber reports jenkins plugin I am using "Number of failed scenarios" parameter.

Out of 20 scenarios, 10 failed. So under Build Status(cucumber reports plugin) - Cucumber Reports in Jenkins I gave "Number of failed scenarios" = 10 However still job is not passed.

Please let me know what is wrong?

PS: There is one field in plugin "Build Status" is by default "Left Unchanged", It has only 2 other values "Failure" & "Unstable" but NOT PASS. Not sure if this has to be changed.

Ref: [How to make jenkins build pass if cucumber scenarios pass percentage is 80%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084429/how-to-make-jenkins-build-pass-if-cucumber-scenarios-pass-percentage-is-80/57089263#57089263)

Answer (score 0):

number of failed scenarios must be above 10, if you declared failedScenariosNumber: 10.